# Minikube run flask docker fail with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, minikube

I am new in Kubernetes, and I want to run the simple flask program on docker in Kubernetes. The image in docker could work successfully, but when I start the K8s.yaml with `kubectl apply -f k8s.yaml` and execute `minikube service flask-app-service` the web result reply fail with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, and pods status `Error: ErrImageNeverPull`.

app.py:

```python
# flask_app/app/app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./app /app/
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]
```

K8s.yaml:

```yaml
---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: flask-app-service
    spec:
      selector:
        app: flask-app
      ports:
      - protocol: "TCP"
        port: 5000
        targetPort: 5000


    
---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: flask-app
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: flask-app
      replicas: 3
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: flask-app
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: flask-app
            image: flask_app:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
```

After deploying I try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:51145` from a browser, but it fails to connect with an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message.  I have a [screenshot showing a more detailed Chinese-language error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXtW3.png) if that detail is helpful.

---

update:

After switch `imagePullPolicy` from `never` to `Always` or `IfNotPresent`, the pod still can't run
[image]
I try the `docker images` command it show the image exist:
[image]
But when I pull image with docker pull, it show me the error:
[image]
After docker login still not work:
[image]

p.s. I follow the website to pratice: https://lukahuang.com/running-flask-on-minikube/

Comment: You will need to use port-forward to expose minikube service to external ip-port

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running to build and run this image?  If the pod is not starting up then you won't be able to connect to it.  For Minikube there are [a couple of ways to make the image available](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/).

Comment: Why are you using the same port for all the containers?
I don't think that will work. You need to assign different ports to each containers or better still create different instances like 3737:5000,  2020:5000 so the external port can be anything while the internal port remains as 5000. That should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error in the question:

> pods status Error: ErrImageNeverPull.

pod doesn't start because you have `imagePullPolicy: Never` in your deployment manifest. Which means that if the image is missing, it won't be pulled anyway.

This is from official documentation:

> The imagePullPolicy for a container and the tag of the image affect
> when the kubelet attempts to pull (download) the specified image.

You need to switch it to `IfNotPresent` or `Always`.

See more in [image pull policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy).

After everything is done correctly, pod status should be `running` and then you can connect to the pod and get the response back. See the example output:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
ubuntu   1/1     Running   0             4d
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but after switch from never to Always or IfNotPresent, it still not work for me.

Comment: @Howard This is because you created an image and it's stored locally, however kuberneres is run in `minikube` which is a separate VM which does NOT have this image stored. You need to push this docker image to docker hub with your account and then kubelet will pull it for you. OR you can try to connect to the `minikube vm` using `minikube ssh` and build this image inside the minikube VM so it'll be presented on the VM and kubelet can use this image since it will be stored locally. After you might need to re-create a deployment to trigger the pull image action

Comment: Also for testing purposes you can try already existing flask app image presented on docker hub, for example [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/markbenschop/flask-demo) and you need to change your image to `markbenschop/flask-demo:1.5`. Or another option to find - I'm not sure which one will work out of the box.

Comment: thank you ! you solved my problem : )

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using the same port for all the containers? I don't think that will work. You need to assign different ports to each containers or better still create different instances like 3737:5000, 2020:5000 so the external port can be anything while the internal port remains as 5000. That should work I think

Comment: It doesn't make any difference in that particular OP's config, because there's only 1 (one) container. `Port` and `target-port` can be the same for simplicity since they are related to service already.